# How to refocus camera?

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to read a barcode though my computer's webcam

[image]

but it fails because the ImageCapture won't refocus the camera when I put the code close to it, and this it is blurry:

[image]

Is there anyway to force a refocus to happen?

Comment: No. None of the built in functions has anything for that. 
How would you get it to refocus without Mathematica. You might be able to write a wrapper.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=[image-processing]+focus

Comment: Perhaps the squares at the corners have enough information to guess a PSF and then deconvolve. But we need at least an actual capture to test it

Comment: and not in JPG format, please!

Comment: I mean like here ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam13-43.pdf

Comment: Do you want to trigger a focus change during capture or a post-processing of the blurry image?

Comment: Trigger a focus change

Answer (score 1):

In order to manipulate the camera from Mathematica, requires a device with a SDK  API kit . THis are small software to allow developers manipulate the device. THe SDK will have to be C++ or .NET  and  use the *CCompiler* with  pipe to interact from Mathematica.This is a subject that I been trying to work around.